# Is it possible to render a component inside useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I just wonder, if is it possible to render a component inside a useEffect hook.
I have two components, let's say A and B.
In Component A, I have my useEffect hook as follows.
While testing some condition inside hook, I want to render a component B.

```
export default function A() {
  const [location, setlocation] = usestate(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (condition) {
      <B />; // it does not render anything though
    } else {
      //code
    }
  }, [location]);
}

export default function B() {
  const test = () => {
    console.log("testing");
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title={"Click Me"} onPress={test} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I dont think so , but you can update a state and conditionally render the component

Comment: You have to conditionally return the <B/> after your useEffect hook.

Comment: Functional components render their return value. Anything not in the return value won't be rendered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not where you'd want to use `useEffect` anyway.

Since `location` is a state atom, it changing will cause a rerender, so the effect hook is unnecessary for that. (I assume `// code` is more complicated than what you let on here, though...)

For the equivalent, but working example,

```
export default function A() {
  const [location, setlocation] = useState(null);
  if (condition) {
    return <B />;
  }
  // code
  return null;
}
```

### EDIT based on comments

To force a rerender (unmount + remount) of a component, you can use an arbitrary key for it:

```
export default function A() {
  const [location, setlocation] = useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // ....
  }, [location]);
  return <B key={location} />;
}
```

To force it to rerender based on a condition in an effect,

```
export default function A() {
  const [location, setlocation] = useState(null);
  const [conditionCounter, setConditionCounter] = useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(condition) {
      setConditionCounter(c => c + 1);
    }
  }, [location]);
  return <B key={conditionCounter} />;
}
```

(or maybe just `new Date()` or `Math.random()`, but a counter works.)

Comment: Actually the scenario is, that besides the first render, every time the value of location (state variable) changes, should execute the hook. So, when it does, it should render component B.

Comment: So you mean you don't want `<B />` to be rendered on the first render? Or do you want it to be forcibly re-rendered when the condition changes?

Comment: `<B />`  should render whenever the condition holds true, does not matter first render or when location variable changes. But just every time, condition meets, it should be forcibly re-rendered.